# error: variable 'x' is still repeating at this depth

Tags: macros, rust

I'm trying to write a macro to time how long various functions are executing.

```
macro_rules! timer {
    ($( $x: expr ),+ ) => {
        let now = SystemTime::now();
        let val = $x;

        match now.elapsed() {
            Ok(elapsed) => {
                // This should include a message at some point alongside the timing
                println!("{}", elapsed.as_secs());
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("{:?}", e);
            }
        }
        val
    } 
}
```

but the compiler throws out a `error: variable 'x' is still repeating at this depth`.

In another statically typed language I've tried this in (F#), using closures was the approach that was the simplest. Is it not possible to have a generic macro like this in Rust?

Comment: The problem is that the macro accepts one or more expressions, but it only uses *one*.  What is it supposed to do?  Should the block expand once for each input expression and return only the last?  Or should it return all of them?  Timed together or independently?  And just to add: you *can* do this easily with a regular function; is there some reason you aren't?

Comment: @DK. My understanding of the macro syntax is that it must be zero or one to many repetitions (I'd prefer to just match and evaluate one expression though). As far as why I'm not using a regualar function for timing, I was just trying to get a feel for macros in the language. It's potentially(?) a bad fit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most immediate problem is that you're asking the macro to parse a sequence of one or more expressions, when the expansion is only capable of dealing with one.  So just *ask* for one.

Secondly, you want the expansion to result in an expression, but you've written it to expand to several statements.  To fix that, expand to a block.

Fixing those gives:

```
macro_rules! timer {
    ($x: expr) => {
        {
            let now = SystemTime::now();
            let val = $x;

            match now.elapsed() {
                Ok(elapsed) => {
                    // This should include a message at some point alongside the timing
                    println!("{}", elapsed.as_secs());
                }
                Err(e) => {
                    println!("{:?}", e);
                }
            }
            val
        }
    } 
}
```